# Mostrar y ocultar Div JavaScript con la misma función

Tags: javascript, html5

Ncesito ayuda con esta funcion que no me esta resultando.
quiero que la misma funcion openSection pueda mostrar y ocultar una clase llamada active... ella me muestra bien todo pero a la hora de ocultar no me esta funcionando tengo que hacer otra funcion aparte para ocultarla y no es lo que deseo.

```js
function openSection(color) {
  document.querySelector(`.${color}`).className += ' active';
  if (color) {
    let sections = document.querySelectorAll('div.section:not(.active)');
    for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      sections[i].className += ' not-active';
    }
  } else {
    let sections = document.querySelectorAll('div.section');
    for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      sections[i].className = `section ${sections[i].classList[1]}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben de incluir un [mcve]. Si estas usando clases para controlar que se muestra u oculta deberías incluir el CSS así como también si estas usando un framework, por ejemplo, bootstrap, deberías indicar cual es (incluyendo la versión).

Comment: Has pensado en usar `document.querySelector(\`.${color}\`).classList.toggle('active')`?